# Can't define android ndk in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, android

My android sdk is located in `/root/Android/Sdk` inside this there is a folder `android-ndk`

I tried

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
```

then

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/ndk-bundle/
```

I have also tried

```
export ANDROID_NDK=/root/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/
```

But every time  I want to build something I got

buil

```
build on Linux x86_64
ANDROID_NDK=
You must define ANDROID_NDK before starting.
They must point to your NDK directories.
```

Comment: Have you checked for spaces? Android Studio throws an error when you use spaces in directory names

Comment: @SandeepNeupane yes I have checked

Answer (score 1):

`/root/Android/Sdk` or any other location inside `/root/` requires root privileges to access. I recommend moving your SDK to an new location within the scope of your normal user. 
If you do not want to do that, I suggest running Android Studio with root privileges to access your NDK directory.